# InverseLaplaceTransform does not evaluate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

I am very new to Mathematica and not a mathematician, so the question may be very trivial.

I am trying to find the function $f(t)$ such that

$\qquad e^{-e^{s}} = \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-st}f(t)dt$,

so I tried using the inverse Laplace transform function.

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[Exp[-Exp[s]], s, t ]
```

However, the output I obtain is simply the command itself. I don't understand if such function simply does not exist (not even in complex numbers) or if I need to introduce some kind of constraint.

Comment: If it returns unevaluated, it means Mathematica cannot compute an explicit formula for the inverse transform.

Comment: $$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}[\exp (-\exp (s))](t)=\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^j \delta
   (j+t)}{j!}$$ where: $\delta (j+t)$ is `DiracDelta[j + t]` for `t>0` sum is: `0`

Comment: Thank you! How did you obtain it? I'd like to understand what I was doing wrong

Comment: $$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}[\exp (-\exp
   (s))](t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\sum _{j=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{(-\exp (s))^j}{j!}\right](t)=\sum _{j=0}^{\infty }
   \mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{(-\exp
   (s))^j}{j!}\right](t)=\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^j
   \delta (j+t)}{j!}=0$$ then execute: `Assuming[t > 0, Sum[((-1)^j DiracDelta[j + t])/j!, {j, 0, Infinity}]]`